# Remove Original file after rename with grunt_copy

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, sails.js, grunt-contrib-copy

I want to delete original file after rename file with grunt copy option.
File successfully renamed However, original file stay without deleting.
Find my code below.

```
rename: {
        files: [
            {
                expand: true,
                flatten: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/public/min',
                src: ['production.*.*'],
                dest: '.tmp/public/min/',
                rename: function(dest, src) {
                return dest + src.replace('production','production.v'+timestamp);
            }
            }]
    },
```

Here is the module I use,

```
grunt-contrib-copy
```

Comment: you have to use grunt-contrib-clean to remove file.

Comment: @Vishwanath,  It is very old and no more maintainable one. Not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `grunt-contrib-clean` to remove the file.